# Do you need to use inproc in netMQ to keep one thread for receiving messages or is there a better way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, zeromq

I am just starting to learn NetMQ, derived from zeroMQ. I don't know C or C++ too well so I'm finding the zeroMQ tutorials a challenge, and the NetMQ ones seem to skim a lot. All I want is a two way binding between processes.

app1 ----- Request data ----> app2
app1 <---- Receives data --- app2

The basic example supplied is

```
using (var context = NetMQContext.Create())
using (var server = context.CreateResponseSocket())
using (var client = context.CreateRequestSocket())
{
    server.Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556");
    client.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556");

    client.Send("Hello");

    string fromClientMessage = server.ReceiveString();

    Console.WriteLine("From Client: {0}", fromClientMessage);

    server.Send("Hi Back");

    string fromServerMessage = client.ReceiveString();

    Console.WriteLine("From Server: {0}", fromServerMessage);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And then just change the IPs. No issue there. But from what I understand this will block a thread? What I want is for the client to send a request, then do other stuff. Meanwhile the server receives the message, goes off and gets data or does other processing, and returns the result when it's done. But if I shove a big switch statement in there, do the relevant process and finally return a result, will it block the zeroMQ context/thread? Which leads onto my next question: is zeroMQ context multithreaded?

What I need is the system to work as asynchronously as possible, if I am going completely the wrong direction here I'd appreciate a point in the right one! 
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, yes NetMQContext is thread safe. NetMQSocket is not.

You need to have a dedicate thread for NetMQSocket, one thread can also handle multiple sockets and timers using Poller. You can use the NetMQScheduler to run tasks on the thread as well. Please read the following:

http://netmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/poller/
http://somdoron.com/2013/06/netmq-scheduler/

Comment: Hi Somodoron, thanks for the reply. So from what I gather you need to use up  a thread for a request/receive socket on each app and then use a scheduler to perform tasks. I am just trying to get my head around it. Like, if I have a lot of requests coming through is it possible (and clever?) to have one thread work purely on send/receive and the rest of the apps threads taking this work load?

Comment: The idea is to write a system that react to events. So yo use the netmq socket, block on the receive, get the message, process, reply and block again. If you want to block on more then one socket or need a timer use the Poller. If you have a lot of messages you can have one thread listen to the socket and then distribute the load to other worker threads. You can distribute the load using InProc sockets.